# Jquery UI drag and drop - dragged item dissapears when dropped only on mobile

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, touch

I am trying to get drag and drop working properly and on desktop of laptop pc it is fine.  However, on a mobile device, when I drag and drop, when dropped, the dragged item dissapears underneath (i think) everything else and I really am unable to work out why.

I have uploaded a page showing the problem to http://mailandthings.co.uk/dam1/

I have tried setting the zindex in the draggable code and that makes no difference

```
       var $dragContainer = $("div.drag-container");
        var $dragItem = $("div.drag-item");

        $dragItem.draggable({
            cursor: "move",
            snap: "div.drag-container",
            snapMode: "inner",
            snapTolerance: 10,
            helper: "clone",
            handle: "i",
            zIndex: 10000
        });

        $dragContainer.droppable({
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                var $elem = $(event.toElement);

                var obj = {
                    posX: event.pageX - $dragContainer.offset().left - event.offsetX,
                    posY: event.pageY - $dragContainer.offset().top - event.offsetY,
                    data: $elem.data(),
                    html: $elem.html()
                };
                addElement(obj);
                masterPos.push(obj);

            }
        });

        function addElement(obj) {
            var $child = $("<div>");
            $child.html("<i>" + obj.html + "</i>").addClass("drop-item drop-item-mobile");
            $child.attr("data-type", obj.data.type);
            $child.css({
                top: obj.posY,
                left: obj.posX
            });
            $dragContainer.append($child);
        }
```

If it using jQuery UI Touch Punch 0.2.3

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I found this kind of patch in a similar question. Apparently it makes jQuery UI able to work for mobile devices, but 5 years have passed and I don't know if it will even work now http://touchpunch.furf.com/

Comment: Thanks I will try that.  Do you know if it is possible or not to do a drag and drop without the drag?  By that I mean tap a source object, and then tap a destination point in the droppable area and it will appear there (if that makes sense!)?  The reason I ask is that the screen scrolling about slightly makes using the drap/drop on a mobile device really annoying.  Unless there is a way, on mobile only, to prevent the screen scrolling?

Comment: Well I am sure it is possible to write a function that does that because both of us have seen that somewhere on the internet, and I think jQuery UI is not necessary for that, just store the HTML of the first and second items and swap them.

Comment: I have tried that touchpunch you suggested and I have realised why the drop items are dissapearing (on a mobile device the left edge of the div is coming back with a different value to that of the desktop/non-mobile version) but another more annoying issue is that using that touch punch, it only allow me to do two consecutive drags and then appears to just stop allowing anymore drags.  Have you seen that before?

Comment: No, I only used jQuery UI on desktop so I haven't had the need to use that patch or anything related to mobile phones, sorry

Comment: This code seems overly complex, but I do not see why it would not work. Do yuou see any alerts or errors in console when testing? Do you get the same results when testing in Desktop browser set to Mobile testing mode?

Comment: Why are you using `event.toElement` versus `ui.helper`? I think the issue is that you are not appending the `ui.helper` hence the element is removed after the drag operation is completed. Hard to confirm, but will see if I can work on it.

Comment: To replicate, I need to know the bootstrap, jQuery, jQuery UI and other library versions that you are using.

Comment: Testing here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/g6ojp4ro/7/

Comment: Mobile Testing here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/g6ojp4ro/7/show/

Comment: Ok, with my testing, what I see happening, is that the new `obj` is being appended, but the CSS is positioning it at the same location as the original item. It is not being positioned at the Drop or `stop` location.

Answer (score 0):

There was sort of a logistical issue that I found. Based on your code, I could identify the following state / logic:

- User drags an item (A, B, C) to the car image to indicate a Dent, Scratch, or Heavy Damage

  - The Drop Point indicates where the Type of damage is located
- When the dragged item is dropped, a new object should be created that indicates the Type and stores the location on the car map

  - This new object replaces the dragged item and is appended to the container

To expand on this, you have the following code that is the dragged element, for example:

```
<div class="drag-item ui-draggable" style="">
  <i data-type="A" class="ui-draggable-handle">A</i>Dent
</div>
```

This is important when creating the new object. In your current code, you're requesting data from an object that does not have any data attributes, `$elem.data()`. Remember that this is the `<div>` that contains the `<i>` that has the attribute. So data is `null` or `undefined`. You will want to capture the data from the child element: `$elem.find("i").data()`.

Also, since you append all the HTML to your new object, you make a double wrapped element. `$child` will look like:

```
<div class="drop-item drop-item-mobile">
  <i>
    <div class="drag-item ui-draggable" style="">
      <i data-type="A" class="ui-draggable-handle">A</i>Dent
    </div>
  </i>
</div>
```

I do not think this was your intention. I suspect your intention was to create:

```
<div class="drop-item drop-item-mobile">
  <i>A</i>
</div>
```

Here is an example of all this: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/g6ojp4ro/40/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var theForm = document.forms.form1;
  if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
  }

  function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
      theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
      theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
      theForm.submit();
    }
  }

  var masterPos = [];
  $("#hidpos").val('');

  var $dragContainer = $("div.drag-container");
  var $dragItem = $("div.drag-item");

  $dragItem.draggable({
    cursor: "move",
    snap: "div.drag-container",
    snapMode: "inner",
    snapTolerance: 10,
    helper: "clone",
    handle: "i",
    zIndex: 10000
  });

  $dragContainer.droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var $elem = ui.helper;
      var type = ui.helper.find("i").data("type");
      var $child = $("<div>", {
        class: "drop-item drop-item-mobile"
      }).data("type", type);
      $("<i>").html(type).appendTo($child);
      $child.appendTo($dragContainer).position({
        of: event
      });
      var obj = {
        posX: $child.offset().top,
        posY: $child.offset().left,
        data: $child.data(),
        html: $child.prop("outerHTML")
      };
      masterPos.push(obj);
    }
  });

  $("map").imageMapResize();

  // Save button click
  $('#form1').submit(function(e) { //$("#btnsave").click(function () {
    if (masterPos.length == 0) {
      $("#spnintro").html("Oops!");
      $("#spninfo").html("No position data was entered");
      $("#dvinfo").fadeTo(5000, 500).slideUp(500, function() {});
    } else {
      $("#hidpos").val(JSON.stringify(masterPos));
      $.ajax({
        url: '/handlers/savepositions.ashx',
        type: 'POST',
        data: new FormData(this),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data) {
          $("#spnintro").html("Success!");
          $("#spninfo").html("Position data has been saved");
          $("#dvinfo").fadeTo(5000, 500).slideUp(500, function() {});
        }
      });
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Tested with Mobile client at: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/g6ojp4ro/40/show/ and is working as expected.

Hope that helps.